# How to reassign all privileges to another role in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, permissions

​On an existing PostgreSQL server let say that I have two users "Alice" & "Bob" and I want to clean up my policy because they actually have the same job and should have exactly the same privileges on every objects of the database.

To do that I will create a new group role "Crew" from which they will both automatically inherit so that in the future, administrators only need to deal with the group role "Crew" and eventually add more users to it.

However because I need to be sure that neither Alice nor Bob will by embarrassed in any way by this change I need to transfer existing  ownerships and privileges of both "Alice" & "Bob" to "Crew" while switching to this new policy.

To perform this I should:

1. Create the Crew role
2. Grant Crew to Alice & Bob (with INHERIT)
3. Transfer Ownership of Alice & Bob to Crew
4. Copy privileges from Alice & Bob to Crew *(and keep more elevated privilege on conflict)*

Step **3** is actually easy because there is a built-in command for that:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY Alice TO Crew;
REASSIGN OWNED BY Bob TO Crew;
```

Step **4** however is more complicated because there is no magic command

```
REASSIGN PRIVILEGES FROM Alice TO Crew; --This don't actually exist too bad for me!
```

**So what is the cleanest way transfer all privileges from "Alice" & "Bob" to "Crew" ?**

---

*My question was initially posted on StackOverflow with no answer in ~3 years and was up-voted last week. I required a migration, but StackOverflow admin pointed out that old questions can't be migrated and suggested I should repost here. I'll delete old post on StackOverflow in 1-2 weeks so that any interested user get a chance to notice the new post here. So please don't flag for duplicate on SO before discussing first*

Comment: @McNets while the (self-) accepted answer points into the right direction, it is far from complete.  It might help the OP to extend it, though.  Another tougher nut would be the case of default privileges.

Comment: Also please note that my point by reposting here, after being denied a migration because question was too old, is that there it make more sense to solve this question here than in stackoverflow. I didn't wanted to post the link directly to my old post as I want to delete it in a few weeks and it's really not my goal to draw attention to it but here it was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41465196/how-to-reassign-all-privileges-to-another-role-in-postgresql

Comment: Also yeah I'm looking for a more complete answer that cover at least function, views, materialized view. I'll eventually try answer myself if nobody else got a lead, I'm more at ease with catalogs now than i was 3 years ago.

Comment: NB: for reference I'm putting here the interesting link that @McNets previously pointed out as related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591557/how-to-create-duplicate-role-of-a-user-in-postgres